# Enforce 2FA on user accounts used in Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, two-factor-authentication

I have a GCP project where I work with people external to my team.
For the moment I assigned them Cloud IAM roles, in order to give them permissions to different parts of the project.

But I was asking myself if is it possible to force those users to have 2FA activated on their accounts. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable 2-factor authentication (2FA) for Google accounts. And You can find more information in this following [document](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/securing-gcp-account-security-keys). Keep in mind Google Cloud Project does not have an isolated service to enforce 2-Step Verification for the accounts of a project. However, there is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/71628180) on our side. Instead, [Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251?visit_id=1-636506554458195576-2146144279&rd=1) offers the identity services and endpoint administration that are available in G Suite as a stand-alone product. As an administrator, you can use Cloud Identity to manage your users, apps, and devices from a central location—the Google Admin console.

You can set up Cloud Identity as an administrator by following these [steps](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7389973?hl=en&ref_topic=7555414).

Also, I invite you to take a look at this thread on [StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41939/two-step-vs-two-factor-authentication-is-there-a-difference) that explained about the difference of2-step verification" and 2 factor authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it covers in more detail options I found before asking here. I think I have to explore more deeply Cloud Identity to see if it matches all needs. The extra link at the end of the answer was very helpful to understand differences between 2fa and 2 step. Thanks!